# Finding a date gap (missing date range) within a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On this SQL Server 2008 database I have a table of attendance, students come into school every day and check in, the table looks something like this:

```
SchoolID | StudentID | Date
```

There will be a record for every day for every student on this table. What I want to find out is, given a start date, an end date, and a number of days (gap), find any student that has not checked into school for that number of days. So for example, I need to know which students missed 3 days straight during the month of December, and spit out the list of StudentIDs.

How can I accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can produce date ranges from `startdate` to `enddate` 
then outer join this data with your table, if the student wouldn't have come consider it as 1 then summarize this data.

for generating date range you can use this function as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange]
(     
      @Increment              CHAR(1),
      @StartDate              DATETIME,
      @EndDate                DATETIME
)
RETURNS  
@SelectedRange    TABLE 
(IndividualDate DATETIME)
AS 
BEGIN
      ;WITH cteRange (DateRange) AS (
            SELECT @StartDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DateRange)
                  END
            FROM cteRange
            WHERE DateRange <= 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, @EndDate)
                  END)

      INSERT INTO @SelectedRange (IndividualDate)
      SELECT DateRange
      FROM cteRange
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 3660);
      RETURN
END
GO
```

then

```
    select sum(isAbsent) absentDays, s.studentid from
    (
    select case when studentid is null then 1 else 0 end isAbsent,individualDate,s.studentid from DateRange('d', '01/11/2014', '30/11/2014') d
cross join tblstudent s
    left outer join yourtable on yourtable.Date = d.IndividualDate and yourtable.studentid = s.studentid 
    ) x
    group by s.studentid
    having sum(isAbsent) > 3
```

Comment: This query seems to return the list of days that NO student checked in. If you run the inner query by itself, you get that, when running the whole thing, you get "isAbsent 31 | StudentID NULL"

Comment: I have changed my query would you check that now

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this. I think you will be able to figure out you own answer from that.This solution take care of the weekend days and holidays :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d33f/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE attendance
    ([SchoolID] int, [StudentID] int, [Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO attendance
    ([SchoolID], [StudentID], [Date])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2014-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-02 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-03 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-04 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-05 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-10 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-11 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-15 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-16 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-17 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-18 00:00:00'),
    (1, 1, '2014-12-19 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-02 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-10 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-11 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-15 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-16 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-17 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-18 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2014-12-19 00:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE holidays
    ([Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO holidays
    ([Date])
VALUES
    ('2014-12-22 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-23 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-24 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-25 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-26 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-29 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-30 00:00:00'),
    ('2014-12-31 00:00:00')
;


CREATE TABLE students
    ([StudentID] int, [Name] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO students
    ([StudentID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'John'),
    (2, 'Peter')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @start DATE, @end DATE
SELECT @start = '20141201', @end = '20141231'

;WITH tdate AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
)

SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM students s 
INNER JOIN attendance a ON s.StudentID = a.StudentID
INNER JOIN tdate ON DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) = a.Date
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING 
(SELECT count(*)
FROM tdate
LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h ON DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) = h.Date
WHERE h.date is null
AND DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start)) not in (1,7))
- COUNT(*) >= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d33f/4/0)**:

```
|  NAME |
|-------|
| Peter |
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT s.StudentID, d.Date
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) as Date
FROM tdate
LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays h ON DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) = h.Date
WHERE h.date is null
AND DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start)) not in (1,7)) d ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance a ON s.StudentID = a.StudentID AND d.Date = a.Date
WHERE a.StudentID IS NULL
ORDER BY s.StudentID, d.Date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d33f/24/0)**:

```
| STUDENTID |       DATE |
|-----------|------------|
|         2 | 2014-12-03 |
|         2 | 2014-12-04 |
|         2 | 2014-12-05 |
```

Comment: Fabien, elegant solution. Thanks.

How can I go about returning two more columns specifying the gap FROM and TO date of that student? For example, like he missed from the 4th to the 10th or something? Is that possible with your query?

Comment: My UPDATE will give you missing date. You can start from this and figured out a way to extract the gap